# Problem with toggling class list with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why isn't this JavaScript working to toggle the `change` class on click?

I originally followed a [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_icon.asp) for creating a toggleable hamburger menu, which worked, but I wanted to try converting the onClick attribute in the HTML (originally added to div with class `hamburger-menu`) to one in a separate file. When I click the hamburger menu, it's not doing anything.

What I'm trying:

```js
let hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger-container');

hamburger.onClick = () => {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('change');
}
```

```css
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-container">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Additionally here's a JS Fiddle -- the menu is set to display none in the regular view but it's visible in mobile view.

Comment: `.onClick =` Programming is often case-sensitive. Use `onclick`

Comment: Aagghh, thank you. I would delete the question but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `transforms` were missing `transitions` and the event handler should use either `event.target` or `event.currentTarget`.

### Demo

```js
let hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');

hamburger.onclick = toggleChange;

function toggleChange(event) {
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('change');
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transition: transform 0.75s;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transition: transform 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `onclick` not `onClick`.

```js
let hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger-container');

hamburger.onclick = () => {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('change');
}
```

```css
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-container">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic. Flag and close them instead of posting an answer.